Process of reconnecting rating for a large country that been excluded from FIDE for a many years
If a large country with a population with many active chess players was expelled from FIDE for many years how would the rating system be reconnected?
They would have hundreds of thousands of players who have been improving without playing a single rated game.   This would include many children who got a rating in the 1400s before disconnection, but now have a skill level in the 2000s with a significant number having skill levels of a candidate master but rated in the 1400s.  (Also such former children who no longer have a K of 40)
There would also be many chess players in their 50/60s with a K of 10 who skill level have significantly declined from their rating while still being active tournament players.
So what are the issues and how could they be solved?


If a large country with a population with many active chess players was expelled from FIDE for many years how would the rating system be reconnected?

The rating system would not have to be "reconnected" because that's not how it works.
A few years ago Bulgaria was in dispute with FIDE and was suspended from FIDE membership. That did not disconnect Bulgarian chess players from their ratings or even prevent them from playing FIDE rated chess. The way FIDE dealt with this was that all Bulgarian chess players had their federation changed from BUL to FID. This happened automatically, without consultation or consent from the players themselves. This was in effect from November 2017 until November 2018. At this time Bulgaria had 34 GMs.
The dispute was between FIDE and Bulgaria and not between FIDE and Bulgarian players and so Bulgarian players were not punished. This included Bulgarian players playing in FIDE rated tournaments in Bulgaria during the period of the Bulgarian federation's suspension.
Here, for instance, is the list of tournaments for May 2018. And here are details of the 2018 BULGARIAN CHESS CHAMPIONSHIP FOR GIRLS U12 - 2018 showing all the Bulgarian girls with FID registration not BUL.

I assume there was no rated play in Bulgarian, so only players who could travel had their rating updated?    So many fast-improving younger players did not have any rated games yet their skill continued to improve.

@IanRingrose You assume wrong. See edits

How are results in rated games submitted for tournaments in a county when the county has been expelled from FIDE?
